# iOS apps - Store formulas/business logic offline

Tags: ios, offline-caching

What is the best way to save complex mathematical formulas/Business Logic offline, retrieve them and use them in iOS apps?

Currently in the app I am developing, I am retrieving simple business logic/formulas(involving basic mathematical operations like +, -, *, /) through a Web Service(received as a String and updated for each sync) and saving them in the local SQLite DB as a string again. And for using these formulas in my objective-c code, am doing some relatively complex manipulations to perform the necessary operations using the formula String(from DB). For simple formulas this will work, albeit a bit of coding effort. But for more complex calculations, obviously this will not work.

Is their a more efficient method for consuming and using these formulas offline?

For eg. Say the user is filling out a form. Based on the input he has entered for Questions Q1, Q2 & Q3 , an amount should be calculated and displayed for Question Q4.

Like Q4 = (Q1 + Q2) * Q3.

This formula will be changing dynamically based on a category selection. These are simple calculations that are currently happening; but moving on there might be more dynamic calculations with multiple formulas.

Hope this explains my question a bit more.

Comment: What kind of formulas? Can you give an example? The question is quite vague.

Comment: @BaniUppal Sorry.. have updated my question. It's basic mathematical formulas but will be dynamic and involve more parameters.

Comment: You can simply have a method for each category in a Common class, something like Utilities. You might want to have an enum for each category. Based on the category, you have a method that takes params and returns a value, compute in that method. Why do you need to store the string in Core Data? Core Data/SQLite should be used when there is a lot of data, has relationships among data, and the schema is a bit complex. Makes sense?

Comment: @BaniUppal Thanks for the suggestion. Firstly I am using Core Data because as you imply, the schema is complex. Many-to-many relationships exists between entities and these formulas are just a part of one such entity. Continuing in the next comment...

Comment: As to why I am storing the formula string in Core Data, it's because the formula might be constantly changing with each web service sync. This is where I am stumped for lack of a more efficient approach, the formula storage/updation part. The Categories sounds like a good idea, but with each sync there's every chance of the params' properties changing(like datatype, number of params). In this case, will the category methods really work? Coz then the method declarations and definitions also need to change dynamically, right?